# Cannot find text which appears in the browser page in page html source code

Tags: html, browser, display

I am trying to read a price information on an HTML page. The price is displayed on the browser page, but not in the HTML source code.
Is it possible to get exactly what appears in the browser page ?

The URL of the page is the following: https://www.mr-bricolage.fr/ponceuse-a-bande-pbs-75-a-bosch.html?magasin=faverolles

I read the page source code and collected the document with GoQuery

There is only one "meta" node with a different price information. The source code of the page does not show the price itself:
Tag: 
Real price as displayed: 119

Answer (score 0):

Here is where I found the price in the HTML code:

```
<span class="price">119,00&nbsp;€</span>
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Hi Paul, where did you find this tag in the code ? I did not find it. If I search "119" it appears nowhere

Comment: I found it via the page inspector in the chrome console.

Comment: Are you sure you use the very same URL ? When I use firefox and choose "view source code", I cannot find the tag. Yet the price is rendered in the Firefow browser correctly

Comment: Now I used your URL again and now the price is gone, but when I change the store I instantly get a price. Maybe the product is not available in this store?

Comment: Ce produit est momentanément indisponible.
There you can see that it is not available right now

Comment: Yes, the behavior of this website is strange. Thank you for your support.